# New array dimension on break line

Tags: arrays, vba, clipboard

I'm putting data from the clipboard into my array and splitting it by new lines. But I also need a second dimension splitted by tabs, but don't know how? The data in clipboard is supposed to have a fixed size, so the number of parts will be the same for each line.

What I have so far

```
Private Sub btnPaste_Click()

    Dim Clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
    Dim arrClip As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim msg As String


    On Error GoTo ERRORHAND

    Set Clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
    Clipboard.GetFromClipboard

    str = Clipboard.GetText(1)
    arrClip = Split(str, vbLf)

    For i = LBound(arrClip) To UBound(arrClip)
        msg = msg & arrClip(i) & vbLf
    Next

    MsgBox (msg)

    Exit Sub

ERRORHAND:
    If Err <> 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Description
End Sub
```

This gives me an array with new elements on each new line from clipboard, but I don't know how to add elements to a second dimension on each 'tab' found in clipboard?

Example of data in clipboard and how I want it to fill the array

Data in clipboard

```
Data00        Data10        Data20        Data30
Data01        Data11        Data21        Data31
Data02        Data12        Data22        Data32
Data03        Data13        Data23        Data33
etc...
```

Should be corresponding array element

```
Array(0,0)    Array(1,0)    Array(2,0)    Array(3,0)
Array(0,1)    Array(1,1)    Array(2,1)    Array(3,1)
Array(0,2)    Array(1,2)    Array(2,2)    Array(3,2)
Array(0,3)    Array(1,3)    Array(2,3)    Array(3,3)
etc...
```

Comment: I do not see any other way than cycling through every line and splitting the values into new arrays. But I would advise you to use a collection instead of an array to store the arrays per line instead. The problem with a multidimensional array would be that number of the parts that you get from splitting by tab may vary from line to line which would require you to set the second dimension of your array to the max ubound value.

Comment: @Tom The data in clipboard is supposed to have a fixed size, so the number of parts will be the same for each line. But I don't know how to look for tabs eg. "if str char is tab then..."?

Comment: A `[tab]` is `Chr(9)` . You are splitting on `Chr(10)` (vbLF) but may have vbCRLF in the data (`Chr(13)&Chr(10)`) . Replace vbCRLF with vbLF before the split.

Comment: from which tool do you call this sub? In excel you could even paste the clipboard to a worksheet and read back the values, it would require less programming from you. Note that this way numbers will be converted to numbers instead of text (you will loose e.g. leading zeros if your data contain them).

Comment: @MátéJuhász it's excel but the number / text problem can be solved using PasteSpecial Format:="Text" when / if I want to paste numbers. The idea of this programming is to not have to paste the data into the sheet before processing, so pasting clipboard to worksheet and then read is not the solution

Comment: To split on a tab just use vbtab:
Split("Hello" & vbtab & "hello" & vbtab & "hello", vbtab)(2) will give you hello (what a surprise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code with some adds (hope it helps)

```
Sub btnPaste_Click()

    Dim Clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
    Dim arrClip As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim msg As String

    Dim arrClip2 As Variant
    Dim arrClipBid() As Variant
    Dim ii As Integer

    'On Error GoTo ERRORHAND

    Set Clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
    Clipboard.GetFromClipboard

    str = Clipboard.GetText(1)
    arrClip = Split(str, vbLf)

    ReDim arrClipBid(LBound(arrClip) To UBound(arrClip), 0 To 0)

    For i = LBound(arrClip) To UBound(arrClip)
        arrClip2 = Split(arrClip(i), Chr(9))
        If MaxLen < UBound(arrClip2) Then
            MaxLen = UBound(arrClip2)
            ReDim Preserve arrClipBid(LBound(arrClip) To UBound(arrClip), 0 To MaxLen)
        End If
        For ii = LBound(arrClip2) To UBound(arrClip2)
            arrClipBid(i, ii) = arrClip2(ii)
            msg = msg & "(" & i & ", " & ii & ")" & arrClip2(ii)
        Next ii
        msg = msg & vbLf
    Next

    MsgBox (msg)

    Exit Sub

ERRORHAND:
    If Err <> 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the `0 To 0` do in the line `ReDim arrClipBid(LBound(arrClip) To UBound(arrClip), 0 To 0)`?

Comment: @Krusing it sets the length of the second dimension

Comment: But why is it set from `0 To 0`? Should'nt it be set from `0 To 1`?

Comment: @Krusing It starts with one dimension (`0`) and after (on `ReDim Preserve arrClipBid(LBound(arrClip) To UBound(arrClip), 0 To MaxLen)`) are added more dimensions